# How to put a QLineEdit into QTableView cell PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

So here is my model,view and proxy model:

```
class example(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(druglist, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumWidth(745)
        self.UI()
    def UI(self):
        self.table_view=QTableView()
        self.table_model=QStandardItemModel()
        self.table_proxy=QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.table_proxy.setSourceModel(self.table_model)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.table_proxy)
```

I'm going to put QLineEdits for each column of my table for filtering purpose.
How should i do this?

Comment: Do you mean line edit for each item, or just for the column header?

Comment: Just for column header,like set of line edits in first row of my table.searching for items in a column via a line edit inside the table (instead of outside line edit search field)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a QCompleter in a QTableView with Qt and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947003/using-a-qcompleter-in-a-qtableview-with-qt-and-python)

Comment: @tmoreau It didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [delegate](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstyleditemdelegate.html) can do that. Here's a basic example.

The table view's delegate decides which widget should be used when editing a cell. In this example the delegate is only applied to the first column. The QLineEdit widget has a character limit of 3 so that you can tell the difference between it and the other columns (which otherwise look the same).

```
class ExampleDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        line_edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
        line_edit.setMaxLength(3)
        return line_edit


class Example(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.build_ui()

    def build_ui(self):       
        self.table_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(4, 2)
        self.delegate = ExampleDelegate()
        self.table_view = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, self.delegate)
        self.table_view.setModel(self.table_model)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.table_view)
        self.layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Comment: You can also get your delegate to return a QComboBox if you want a predefined list of options @IMAN4K

Comment: Thank you very much.but for my general purpose(filtering for column item) how should i connect line_edit.textChanged to my proxy model(in subclassing ItemDelegate).should i use ItemDelegate in a different way?thanks again